# Making a numbered list

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am trying to make this into a list and it is giving me an `hbox overfull` and justifying the text to the right in the pdf.  I simply want to put numbers on this and make a list.

```
\begin{enumerate}

\list A confined aquifer with no leaking.
\list The wells are fully penetrating.
\list The cone of depression is symetric around the well.
\list The aquifer is homogenous and isotropic meaning that the hydrauli cconductivity (k) does not change.
\list There is not vertical flow ie. no recharge and water is flowing into the well only.
\list Drawdown in the well occurs instanteously ie water comes into the well from the surrounding rock without delay.
\list  All flow is Darcian.  
\list  At t=o, meaning start of the test the drawdown(s) is zero.
\list The drawdown at an infinite distance from the well is zero.
\list Volume of water entering the well is equal to the pump rate (steady-state conditions). 
\list The well box is not being resupplied with water which means we have an infinitely small well.

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. To highlight code you can just select it and click the button marked `{}` above the text field. This will indent blocks by four spaces, or add backticks (`\``) around inline code.

Comment: For more details on list environments in LaTeX, the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures) is a good start.

Answer (score 52):

To start a new list item you should use the `\item` command within one of the list environments (`itemize`, `enumerate`, `description`), not `\list`. So try

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First points
  \item Second
  \item Etc.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: @Stephen The response from `@Torbjørn T.` seems a correct solution and to benefit other readers of this post you may want to mark it as an `Answer` or let us know if you need further clarification.

Comment: I tested. This should be marked as an `Answer`.

Comment: @nam Stephen hasn't commented on my answer, so he won't have been notified of your comment. He also hasn't logged on since 2013, so I think it's unlikely that he'll look at this again.